# Zend Rest Client issue

Tags: web-services, rest, zend-framework, php, zend-rest

i have the codes below

```
class ReservationController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        $soap = new Zend_Rest_Server();
        $soap->setClass('Someclass');

        $soap->handle();
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
private $_URI = "http://www.mysite.local/crm/reservation";
    public function clientAction() {
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $client = new Zend_Rest_Client($this->_URI);
       echo $client->sayHello('nisanth')->get();

    }

}
```

and the class and method as

```
<?php
class Someclass
{
/**
* Say Hello
*
* @param string $who
* @return string
*/
function sayHello($who)
{
    return "Hello $who";

}
}
```

but while calling this 
i got an error

> **Message: REST Response Error: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^**

pls help me to solve this issue

Comment: Just came across the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're not returning an XML response from your REST request. SimpleXML only fails when it doesn't get valid XML as a parameter.

Make sure that your REST server is actually employing Zend_REST_Server, which outputs the return value of a function into an XML response.

For more info on how Zend_Rest_Client works: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.client.html

For more info on Zend_Rest_Server:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html